# Conjecture: $a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+b^{(2(1-b))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+c^{(2(1-c))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{c}{n}\leq 1$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation, conjectures

Hi it's a conjecture inspired by a work of Vasile Cirtoaje :

### Claim :

Let $0.5\geq a \geq b \geq c\geq 0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ and $n\geq 1$ a natural number then we have :

$$a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+b^{(2(1-b))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+c^{(2(1-c))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{c}{n}\leq 1$$

To prove it I have tried Bernoulli's inequality as we have :

$$a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}\leq 1-(1-a)(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

But it's not enough and wrong.

I have tested for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.Moreover the equality case is $a=b=0.5$.

Case $n=1$ :

As in my previous posts we have the inequality $x\in[0,0.5]$ :

$$x^{2(1-x)}\leq 2^{2x+1}x^2(1-x)$$ applying this for each variable we want to show :

$$2^{2a+1}a^2(1-a)+2^{2b+1}b^2(1-b)+2^{2(1-(a+b))+1}(1-(a+b))^2(a+b)+1-(a+b)\leq 1$$

Now by Bernoulli's inequality we have:

$$2^{2x+1}\leq 2(1+2x)$$

Remains to show :

$$2(1+2a)a^2(1-a)+2(1+2b)b^2(1-b)+2(1+2(1-(a+b)))(1-(a+b))^2(a+b)+1-(a+b)\leq 1$$

Wich is wrong because we have an equality case at $b=c=0.25$ and $a=0.5$!

### My question :

Have you a counter-example or later (if it's true) a proof ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The lack of symmetry is...concerning.

Comment: Why is the extra $\frac{c}{n}$ included?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to change a question after receiving an answer. Doing so invalidates the answer, and confuses future readers of this thread.

Comment: Related on Meta (attribution goes to Martin Sleziak for [finding the links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56242401#56242401)): [question edited to change meaning](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304/42969), [Editing a question after receiving one or more answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26565/42969), [Is that OK to modify a question significantly?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20103/42969).

Comment: @MartinR no problem I change the question !

Answer (score 2):

I have found a counterexample:
$$a=\frac{2}{5},\ b=\frac{3}{10},\ c=\frac{3}{10},\ n=1.$$
This gives:
$$a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+b^{(2(1-b))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+c^{(2(1-c))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{c}{n} = \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{\frac{6}{5}}+\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{\frac{7}{5}}+\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{\frac{7}{5}}+\frac{3}{10}\approx 1.0037 >1.$$

Comment: @eriksatie Nevertheless, it seems that the inequality could be true if tighter bounds are applied on the parameters, so I would keep trying if I were you...

Comment: Have you a counter-example for $n\ge 2$ ?

Comment: No, I don't. It seems to me that the inequality is true for $n\ge2$ (I just tried several plots), but I do not know how to prove it. And with the new bounds, the case $n=1$ seems true too.

Answer (score 0):

if you pick $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$ and $n=1$ then
$$a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+b^{(2(1-b))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+c^{(2(1-c))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{c}{n}=(\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{4}{3}} +(\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{4}{3}}+(\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{1}{3}\geq \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}>1$$
And even if you delete the last term $\frac{c}{n}$ in this case it would be also bigger than 1.
It is also valid for $n=2$ because you will have:
$$a^{(2(1-a))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+b^{(2(1-b))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+c^{(2(1-c))^{\frac{1}{n}}}+\frac{c}{n}=3\cdot(\frac{1}{3})^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}} +\frac{1}{6}=3^{1-\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}+\frac{1}{6}=1.010368679... $$

Comment: Can delete it ? Just because $(\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{4}{3}}<\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: You're right, but anyway $(\frac{1}{3})^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}+ (\frac{1}{3})^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}+(\frac{1}{3})^{\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}}+\frac{1}{6}=1,01...$